# Asset fingerprint differs between servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am deploying my rails 3.2.14 application to 2 different servers with a load balancer in front of them.  The assets are currently being precompiled on the server (via capistrano deployment).

For some reason the fingerprint on the application.js file is different between the two servers.  The source file is identical.  IF I remove the `//= require_tree .` from the application.js then they both magically have the same fingerprint.

I've come across a few posts that mention this issue, but never really address the root cause:

- https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/158#issuecomment-1837340
- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2569#issuecomment-1879181

I'm trying to avoid pre-compiling the assets locally as a way to solve this issue (at least for now...).

Comment: Could you try listing each file individually in `application.js`? I wonder if `require_tree` delegates ordering to the file system, and for whatever reason your two servers are returning the contents of their asset directories in different orders.

Comment: I think you are probably right. Will try tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to easily work around this issue (i.e. did not want to fully spell out the assets tree in my application.js), so I ended up overriding the `deploy:assets` task to compile assets locally and push to each server in my cluster.

```
namespace :deploy do
  namespace :assets do
    desc 'Run the precompile task locally and scp to server'
    task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      if releases.length <= 1 || capture("cd #{latest_release} && #{source.local.log(source.next_revision(current_revision))} vendor/assets/ app/assets/ | wc -l").to_i > 0
        run_locally "bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
        run_locally "cd public; tar -zcvf assets.tar.gz assets"
        top.upload "public/assets.tar.gz", "#{shared_path}", :via => :scp
        run "cd #{shared_path}; tar -zxvf assets.tar.gz"
        run_locally "rm public/assets.tar.gz"
        run_locally "bundle exec rake assets:clean"
      else
        logger.info 'Skipping asset pre-compilation because there were no asset changes'
      end
    end
  end
end
```