# Rails assets fingerprints differ on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, docker, asset-pipeline

(I've already tried [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387082/asset-fingerprint-differs-between-servers))

I'm using a docker image with Ruby 2.2.2p95 and Rails 4.2.3 to run 2 containers on 2 different servers, but although I use the same image, they both serve desktop.js with different fingerprint:

When I run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

on both machines, they both generate the js files with the same fingerprint -

```
desktop-<FINGRPRINT>.js
```

However, when I access the my homepage, one of the servers serves a different `desktop-<OTHER-FINGERPRINT>.js`

How can it be? Is there some caching mechanism I'm unaware of? I tried taking the server off and on again, but the same problem persists, and with the exact same `desktop-<OTHER-FINGERPRINT>.js`